# How to document a function generator with jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am trying to document a function generator but without success, this is an example:

```
function genericObjectGenerator(tagname) {
  var specificObject = function () {};

  specificObject.getClassName = function () {
    return tagname;
  }

  specificObject.prototype.sayHello = function(name) {
    return tagname + " says hello to " + name;
  }

  return specificObject;
}

var MyObject = genericObjectGenerator("object1");

var myObjectInstance = new MyObject();

myObjectInstance.sayHello();
```

How should i document the genericObjectGenerator and its specificObject functions in order to get JSDoc (and IntelliJ) to resolve the sayHello properly.

Comment: Anti-patterns need more discouragement.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
/**
 * @param {string} tagname - the name of the tag
 * @returns {specificObject}
 */

function genericObjectGenerator(tagname) {
    var specificObject = function () {};

    specificObject.getClassName = function () {
        return tagname;
    };

    /**
     * @param {string} name - name as string
     * @returns {string}
     */

    specificObject.prototype.sayHello = function(name) {
        return tagname + ' says hello to ' + name;
    };

    return specificObject;
}

var MyObject = genericObjectGenerator('object1');

var myObjectInstance = new MyObject();

myObjectInstance.sayHello(123); // mark as warning
myObjectInstance.sayHello('123'); // not marking
```